# How to send an error message from the apollo- server

Tags: node.js, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

this my code

in apollo clients I use useMutation.

**apollo clients**

```
  const [addTodo, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(gql);
```

**apollo-server**

```
 Mutation: {
    signUp: async (_, formSignUp, { models: { User }, res }) => {
      try {
        const user = new User(formSignUp);
        await user.save();
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
        res.cookie("darkAmasia", token, {
          httpOnly: true
        });
        return "string";
      } catch (error) {
        ?????????
      }
    }
  }
```

What should I write in catch ? to send a message `{status:400,error:true}`in useMutation error.
I heard that `throw new ApolloError` is used for these purposes.But I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about error handling [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/)

you can create your own Error class which extends ApolloError and pass status as default attribute.

```
    Mutation: {
    signUp: async (_, formSignUp, { models: { User }, res }) => {
      try {
        const user = new User(formSignUp);
        await user.save();
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
        res.cookie("darkAmasia", token, {
          httpOnly: true
        });
        return "string";
      } catch (error) {
        throw new ApolloError("Something went wrong", "BAD_INPUT",{status:400,error:true});
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why am I getting an error in the console? How to make this not happen?
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL error: Backend request failed`

Comment: Instead of throw try using return

Comment: No, that didn't help either.